# How do i keep items in one row using php array_chunk and javascript filter?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Couldn't find the answer using the search option, so here it goes.

I have a page with the profile pictures of our guests. Using array_chunk i keep them 6 at a time on 1 row:

```
foreach (array_chunk($smoelenboek, 6, true) as $array) {
   echo '<div class="row">';
   foreach($array as $smoel) { 
     if(empty($smoel['foto'])){
       //nog geen foto ingevoerd    
       $foto = "/images/pasfotoman.jpg";
     }Else{
       //wel een foto ingevoerd    
       $foto = "/images/gastenfotos/".$smoel['foto'];     
     }
?>
     <div class="smoelfilter col-md-"><img title="<?=$smoel['voornaam']?>       
        <?=$smoel['achternaam']?>" src="<?=$foto?>"> <h3 class="fotonaam"><p>
        <b><?=$smoel['voornaam']?> <?=$smoel['achternaam']?></b></p></h3> 
     </div>
<?php  }
        echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

There are a lot of guests so I added a filter field using javascript:

```
<script>
   $("#filterveld").on('keyup', function(){ 
      $('.smoelfilter').hide();
      var txt = $('#filterveld').val();
      $('.smoelfilter').each(function(){
         if($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) !== -1){
            $(this).show();
         }     
      });    
   });
</script>
```

It works, however when I filter the guests they al appear on different rows. (which makes sense).

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Update: edited code without the rows.

```
 //foreach loop en rows opmaken

        foreach($smoelenboek as $smoel) { 

        if(empty($smoel['foto'])){
        //nog geen foto ingevoerd    

           $foto = "/images/pasfotoman.jpg";



        }Else{
        //wel een foto ingevoerd    
         $foto = "/images/gastenfotos/".$smoel['foto'];     
        }


        ?>

          <div class="smoelfilter col-lg-2"><img style="height:auto;box-shadow:1px 1px 5px gray;" title="<?=$smoel['voornaam']?> <?=$smoel['achternaam']?>" src="<?=$foto?>"> <h3 class="fotonaam" style="text-align:center;"><p><b><?=$smoel['voornaam']?> <?=$smoel['achternaam']?></b></p></h3></div>


         <?php  }  ?>
```

part of output:

```
<div class="smoelfilter col-lg-2" style="display: none;"><img style="height:auto;box-shadow:1px 1px 5px gray;" title="Bas Broens" src="/images/pasfotoman.jpg"> <h3 class="fotonaam" style="text-align:center;"><p><b>Bas Broens</b></p></h3></div>

<div class="smoelfilter col-lg-2" style="display: block;"><img style="height:auto;box-shadow:1px 1px 5px gray;" title="Christien Bevelander ( Hurkmans) " src="/images/pasfotovrouw.jpg"> <h3 class="fotonaam" style="text-align:center;"><p><b>Christien Bevelander ( Hurkmans) </b></p></h3></div>
```

[result without filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3FDu.png)

[result with filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdNht.png)

Answer (score 0):

based on what I understood from your issue:

you have 6 profile pictures in each row, so when you filter them you may have up to 6 profile pictures encapsulated in a row, and here is the issue, the number of profile pictures in the row does affect its display, so a row with one profile picture will remain reserving a full-line block in the page as it was when there are 6 profiles inside it.

So, you should change the way you are displaying the profile pictures, try to restyle your HTML by **removing the rows**, **make each profile picture div displayed as inline-block with a 100% / 6 width** (col-lg-2 if you are using Bootstrap) , OR **use an AJAX function** to get the filtered data and rebuild your rows again.

Comment: You understand what i'm trying to do. I removed the row and used the class="col-lg-2" for the profile-div. The problem i am keeping is that the hidden pictures still have the col-lg-2 class. I think that is the reason why the items ar not next to each other when filtering.

Comment: @BasBroens no they shouldn't, could you update your code please

Comment: @BasBroens please add the output :)

Comment: Done.. i added two divs. First one is not in the filter (name containing "c") second one is displayed.

Comment: @BasBroens they should work fine as this example https://jsfiddle.net/sxewnpya/
but you should pay attention to the responsive matter, so the div class could be `col-lg-2, col-md-2, col-sm-2, col-xs-2` you can use them all or just use the smallest size `col-xs-2`

Comment: i added two images of the result. As you can see there are still "gaps" when using a filter

Comment: @BasBroens are there any custom css properties for these divs ?

Comment: Never mind.. The problem was with the class in the <h3>. I removed it and now it functions perfectly. Thank you so munch